# Subtract one field from another but 1 field is created of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

```
SELECT 
E.`employee_id`,
E.`full_name`,
LE.`no_of_leaves` AS AllocatedLeaves,
MLLT.`leave_type` AS LeaveTypeName,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leave_approval WHERE employee_id = 1 AND MONTH(approval_date) = 11 GROUP BY approval_date) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
LE.`no_of_leaves` - TotalLeavesTaken AS Balance
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE
ON E.`employee_id` = LE.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `ml_leave_type` MLLT
ON MLLT.`ml_leave_type_id` = LE.`ml_leave_type_id`
LEFT JOIN leave_approval LA
ON E.`employee_id` = LA.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN leave_application LAPP
ON LAPP.`application_id` = LA.`leave_application_id`
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLTLA
ON MLLTLA.`ml_leave_type_id` = LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'TotalLeavesTaken' in 'field list'
```

This is what I have tried to do, but got error..

```
LE.`no_of_leaves` - TotalLeavesTaken AS Balance
```

I'm not good in databases, I have to subtract 1 field from another, the first field is ok, but the second field is generated as of subquery. I don't want to run subquery again; is it possible some way to do subtraction without using subquery again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.employee_id, E.full_name, LE.no_of_leaves AS AllocatedLeaves,
       MLLT.leave_type AS LeaveTypeName,
      (LE.no_of_leaves - SUM(CASE WHEN LA.employee_id = 1 AND MONTH(LA.approval_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS balance
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE ON E.employee_id = LE.employee_id
INNER JOIN `ml_leave_type` MLLT ON MLLT.ml_leave_type_id = LE.ml_leave_type_id
LEFT JOIN leave_approval LA ON E.employee_id = LA.employee_id
LEFT JOIN leave_application LAPP ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLTLA ON MLLTLA.ml_leave_type_id = LAPP.ml_leave_type_id
GROUP BY E.employee_id;
```

**EDIT**

**If you want to count the leave balance each employewise**

```
SELECT E.employee_id, E.full_name, LE.no_of_leaves AS AllocatedLeaves,
       MLLT.leave_type AS LeaveTypeName, LA.TotalLeavesTaken, 
      (LE.no_of_leaves - LA.TotalLeavesTaken) AS balance
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE ON E.employee_id = LE.employee_id
INNER JOIN ml_leave_type MLLT ON MLLT.ml_leave_type_id = LE.ml_leave_type_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT LA.employee_id, COUNT(1) As TotalLeavesTaken 
           FROM leave_approval LA 
           WHERE MONTH(LA.approval_date) = 11 
           GROUP BY LA.employee_id
         ) AS LA ON E.employee_id = LA.employee_id
LEFT JOIN leave_application LAPP ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLTLA ON MLLTLA.ml_leave_type_id = LAPP.ml_leave_type_id
GROUP BY E.employee_id;
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, for quick response. 
But according to last answer. the the SUM was not giving accurate answer. as there are many rows repeated in my table cuz of joins.
Your solution seems very good as i dont have to write another query inside. and i have tried your solution, but unfortunately i am getting wrong result.. If it would have worked, i would have loved your solution to use.

Comment: no, i want to deduct leave for each employee as each employee will have his/her own leaves.
I mean emp1 has been allocated 10 leaves then he do take 3 leaves then 7 leaves will remain in balance for emp1.
and other employees will have their own allocated leaves and total taken leaves.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the subquery, you'll want to move the calculation of total leaves taken into a derived table in order to use it again elsewhere in the query.

Also, the subquery itself looks wrong, surely you want to correlate it to the actual employee? And I'm not sure what you intended with the group by, so I've omitted it.

```
SELECT 
  E.`employee_id`,
  E.`full_name`,
  LE.`no_of_leaves` AS AllocatedLeaves,
  MLLT.`leave_type` AS LeaveTypeName,
  lt.TotalLeavesTaken as TotalLeavesTaken,
  LE.`no_of_leaves` - lt.TotalLeavesTaken AS Balance
FROM employee E
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalLeavesTaken
     FROM leave_approval 
     WHERE employee_id = E.`employee_id` AND MONTH(approval_date) = 11 
   ) AS lt -- GROUP BY approval_date doesn't make sense to me
  INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE
    ON E.`employee_id` = LE.`employee_id`
  INNER JOIN `ml_leave_type` MLLT
    ON MLLT.`ml_leave_type_id` = LE.`ml_leave_type_id`
  LEFT JOIN leave_approval LA
    ON E.`employee_id` = LA.`employee_id`
  LEFT JOIN leave_application LAPP
    ON LAPP.`application_id` = LA.`leave_application_id`
  LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLTLA
    ON MLLTLA.`ml_leave_type_id` = LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`
```

Comment: Getting Error Sir,
`Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 25`

Comment: Um, there is no `LIMIT`in either of our queries. Can you post a sample up to [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? I guess another concern here is that `COUNT()`ing the number of leaves taken might also not be intended - you possibly want to sum the actual number of leave days? Unless leave_approval has one row per day taken, of course.